# All of my sculpting tools stopped working. They are just pushing my mesh down with a lot of intensity even though the strength is all the way down

Tags: mesh, sculpting, brushes

[image]I'm very new to blender and I decided to try my hand at sculpting. When I was sculpting a piece of clothing I decided to try and experiment with the clothing filter and since then none of my sculpting tools work. Whenever I try to use any of them they just pull down and tear through the mesh. It is as if my mesh was being pulled down by gravity or something. They also do so with so much intensity even though my brush strength is down. I already tried resetting the scale and the brushes themselves but none of that has worked.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please show some screenshots, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I edited it to show a screenshot. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe apply the scale of your object? Or please share it

Comment: I already tried that, along with all the other things i can apply. how can i send you my file? (thank you btw)

Comment: Use the link given in my first comment or use another platform and share the link to the file here

Comment: Okay it has been uploaded. Hope you can open it!

Comment: You need to copy paste the link it generates

Comment: There it is. I'm so sorry im very new to this, thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring the *Gravity Factor* back to 0:

[image]

Comment: Seriously I couldn't thank you enough! It all works great now. Tysm!!!!

Comment: I didn't even know this option. If you get stuck and don't find the answer, you can still copy paste your objects from a file to another (or append the objects).